# Multi where with select opion in query

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I want to make a multiple select like this

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<select name="age">
<option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="0">18-20</option>
    <option value="1">21-23</option>
    <option value="2">24-27</option>
    <option value="3">28-32</option>
    <option value="4">33-39</option>
    <option value="5">40-49</option>
    <option value="6">50+</option>
</select>
<select name="gender">
    <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="filtrer" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my query is this

```
$retour_messages = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '. mysql_real_escape_string ($premiereEntree) .', '. mysql_real_escape_string ($messagesParPage) .'');
```

i need to make multi where for sorting my result by my select, if someone can help me.

Thx

Comment: you want to use a `multiple` select in your form ?

Comment: yes, for sorting my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a dynamic query to perform this. Start with a basic stub

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
```

Then you need to set the initial clause to  WHERE.

```
 $clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
```

check if `$_POST['filtrer']` is set

```
if(isset($_POST['filtrer'])){//to run PHP script on submit
```

Then start building query using switch  case

```
//age
if(!empty($_POST['age'])){
    switch ($_POST['age']) {
    case 1:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >18 AND <20)";
        break;
    case 2:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >21 AND <23)";
        break;
    case 3:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >24 AND <27)";
        break;
    case 4:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >28 AND <32)";
        break;
    case 5:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >33 AND <39)";
        break;
    case 6:
        $sql .= "$clause (age >40 AND <49)";
        break;
    case 7:
        $sql .= "$clause age >50";
        break;      
}
```

Set clause to AND

```
$clause = " AND ";// Set clause to AND 
}
//gender
if(!empty($_POST['gender'])){
    switch ($_POST['gender']) {
    case 'male':
        $sql .= "$clause gender = male";
        break;
    case 'female':
        $sql .= "$clause gender = female";
        break;
}
}
$sql .=" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT";//. mysql_real_escape_string ($premiereEntree) .", ";  
echo $sql;
}
```

You will require to renumber age option

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
<select name="age">
<option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="0">18-20</option>
    <option value="2">21-23</option>
    <option value="3">24-27</option>
    <option value="4">28-32</option>
    <option value="5">33-39</option>
    <option value="6">40-49</option>
    <option value="7">50+</option>
</select>
```

It would be advisable to use PDO or Mysqli as mysql_ functions are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. gender and age fields should be in your table

```
 $where = array();

if(isset($_POST['age']) && $_POST['age'] !== ''){
   $where[] = ' `age` = ' . (int)$_POST['age'];
}

if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] !== ''){
   $where[] = " `gender` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['gender']))) . "' ";
}

$retour_messages = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users ' . implode(' AND ', $where) . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '. (int)$premiereEntree .', '. (int)$messagesParPage .'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend :

```
if ($_POST['filtrer']){
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$age_ct = count($age);
$gender_ct = count($gender);

$i=0;
while($i < $age_ct){
    $age_SQL .= "'$age[$i]',";
    $i++;
}

if ($age_ct < 1){
    $age_SQL = " age IN('')";
}else{
    $age_SQL = eregi_replace(",$",'',$age_SQL);
    $age_SQL = " AND age IN($age_SQL)";
}

$i=0;
while($i < $gender_ct){
    $gender_SQL .= "'$gender[$i]',";
    $i++;
}

if ($gender_ct < 1){
    $gender_SQL = " gender IN('')";
}else{
    $gender_SQL = eregi_replace(",$",'',$gender_SQL);
    $gender_SQL = " AND gender IN($gender_SQL)";
}

$retour_messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1 $age_SQL $gender_SQL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ". mysql_real_escape_string($premiereEntree).",".mysql_real_escape_string($messagesParPage)." ");

}
```

You need to use `<select name="age[]" multiple>` and `<select name="gender[]" multiple>`

Comment: It work but i want to filter, only when i click on submit, if i don't click on submit i see all the row without filtering, it's possible ?

Comment: In your case : `if ($_POST['filtrer']){ echo //statement }`

Comment: i see , but if i choose any for age and female, he don't work

Comment: Any in my 'Age' select en female in my gender select, he don't work

Comment: if you choose `any` you wanna to display all the results ?

Comment: yes for example, i choose any for age and female, i want to display, all age for female, and another example, if i choose any for gender and 18-20 for age i want to display all gender for 18-20